# Is a [title] tag useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I proposed a [title] tag for the questions a bout the title of books. When people need to understand, or discuss about the meaning of a book, they could use that tag.

Examples:

- [What is the significance of the title of the book Wool?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/473/what-is-the-significance-of-the-title-of-the-book-wool)
- [Meaning of the title "They Shoot Horses, Don't They?"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/615/meaning-of-the-title-they-shoot-horses-dont-they)

What do you think?

Comment: Sound perfectly fine to me, Movies.se also use [similar tag too](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title).

Answer (score 7):

Seems fine to me. My only thought is just that the tag wiki should be clear in when to use it (only when discussing the title of a novel in a literary setting/analysis/discussion).

Comment: Yes. My experience on other sites tells me that new users (at least once we go public and not everyone can create new tags) will be tagging loads of questions with [tag:title] just because they don't know what else to tag it, or because the specific work doesn't have a tag on the site yet. But as long as we're proactive about fixing the tags on new questions, this won't be a problem.